# Simple PHP script for downloading results

Tags: php, asp.net, html

I need to download results from a website using a for loop to compile them.

(Note that it's an ASP request which displays a webpage with these parameters)

I wrote the following code to get me this:

```
<?php
for ($i=10; $i<500; $i++) {
$m = $i*10;

$dl = $query;
$text = file_get_contents($dl);
$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0');
$doc->loadHTML($text);
$aObj = $doc->find('Academic');
if (count($aObj) > 0)
{
   echo "<h4>Found</h4>";
   //Don't download this
}
else
{
   echo "<h4>Not found</h4>";
   //Download this
}
}
?>
```

But it returns several errors. Apparently it can't copy the ASPX file to the HTML DOM. How do I go about doing this? Also, how can I download/save the pages where the string 'Download' is not found?

I also think my method of finding 'Download' in the document is not working. What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Dude, are you serious? You provide a sample link exposing sensitive information of real students???

Comment: Well, it really isn't that sensitive, just some publicly available archived results.

Comment: Here's a screenshot: http://imm.io/11bct
Alternatively, can I somehow download all the files using a for loop and PHP CURL?

Comment: There's no authentication here in the code, in fact you can get to this with a simple browser, I'm sure it's also indexed .. I really don't see a problem with the link in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The website you're attempting to parse contains a lot of errors, therefore you wont be able to use the standard DOMDocument object. You can attempt to use a library such as SimpleHTMLDOM (http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) or phpQuery (https://code.google.com/p/phpquery/) and hope that those are good enough to parse the malformed document.

In case you just need some information it might be easier to use regular expressions and preg_match_all (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) to find every occurrence of 'Academic' for example.

*Note, usually it is not very advisable to use regular expression when working with structured documents such as HTML since you wont be able to take advantage of the structure, but since those documents seem to contain over 300 errors and differ from each other it might be the only way.*